# Problems Implementing IBindableComponent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I need to bind a property to a ToolStripMenuItem. I've searched around and found it impossible, the best workaround seems to be creating a BindableToolStripMenuItem class and implement it yourself. So I've taken some reasonably well established code from the internet:

```
public class BindableToolStripMenuItem : ToolStripMenuItem,IBindableComponent
{
    private BindingContext bindingContext;
    private ControlBindingsCollection dataBindings;
    [Browsable(false)]
    public BindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                bindingContext = new BindingContext();
            return bindingContext;
        }
        set
        {
            bindingContext = value;
        }
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
    {
        get
        {
            if (dataBindings == null)
                dataBindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
            return dataBindings;
        }
    }
}
```

Now all I need is to bind it right? I set up a form with a toolStripMenu and added a property to bind to: No luck. I can check it, but the changes don't seem to filter down into the binding.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Boolean _BindingChecked;
    public Boolean BindingChecked {
        get { return _BindingChecked;  }
        set { _BindingChecked = value; Console.WriteLine(": " + _BindingChecked); }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindableToolStripMenuItem btsmi = new BindableToolStripMenuItem();
        btsmi.Text = "Checkable";
        btsmi.CheckOnClick = true;
        btsmi.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked",this,"BindingChecked"));

        itemsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(btsmi);
    }
}
```

It's definitely doing some of the binding though! If I change "Binding Checked" or "Checked" strings it throws the appropriate error eg:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cannot bind to the property or column BindingChecked2 on the DataSource.
```

It's just any changes (to either, I tested it implementing InotifyChanged going the other way too) don't get applied to the bound property.

Any Idea where I've gone wrong? I've cut things down so much, it's just these two classes, and I've tried starting from scratch with the BdindableToolStripMenuItem, and looked at a fair few other people's implementation (almost all identical) and still can't ever get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the DataSourceUpdateMode of the Binding to OnPropertyChanged, the default is OnValidation but since menu items don't have normal focus behavior I can imagine the default does not work. This allows updates on the menu item to propagate to the BindingChecked property

If you want the reverse, updates to BindingChecked property by code to propagate to the menu item, you must implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the form and raise the event whenever you change the property from code (e.g. in the property set accessor).